# Same PHP code acting differently in two scripts?

Tags: php

So I have a piece of code where I'm trying to download an audio file running from a REST API in progress, it's surroundings look like this:

```
elseif($method == 'synthTTS'){
        //check if all required parameters are accounted for
        checkParameters($data, array('message'));
        $message = $data['message'];
        $message = str_replace(' ', '+', $message);
        $url = "http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=" . $message;
        $path = "tts-mp3/" . str_replace('+', '', $message) . ".mp3";
        // saveUrl($url, $path);
        echo $url . "\n" . $path . "\n";
        $file = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($path, $file);
        exit("Successfully synthesized TTS to " . $path);
    }
```

I pass this "hello world" as the message parameter and the echo reveals the expected $path and $url values("tts-mp3/helloworld.mp3" and "http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=hello+world" respectively). However, when I rest this 'function' no file is saved. After I did this I ran the `file_get_contents` line and the `file_put_contents` line in the PHP interactive shell like so.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $file = file_get_contents("http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=hello+world");
php > file_put_contents("tts-mp3/helloworld.mp3", $file);
```

This worked fine. Which I thought was weird, to further test, I put those two lines of code with the hardcoded $path and $url back into the REST script and it didn't work still. So as a final test I copy/pasted those two lines into a fresh php script and ran it. It worked. So my question is "Why would the same code act completely differently in two different scripts?"

I've tried this code in PHP versions 5.3 and 5.4.

EDIT: So I tried moving the code out of the if block that contains all of my REST functions and put it at the top right below my include/require statements and it worked. So I moved it down one line at a time until it broke.

```
//include all the necessary external libraries
include_once 'ses.php'; //for sending emails of AWS
include_once 'sns.php'; //for the notification service of AWS
include_once 'sqs.php'; //for the queueing service of AWS
include_once 'gearman-client.php'; //for sending jobs to gearman workers
include_once 'vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php'; //for making web requests
include_once 'twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php'; //for using the Twitter API
Requests::register_autoloader();

//IT WORKS IF I PUT THE CODE HERE

//initialize twitter settings
$settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
        'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
        'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    );

//BUT NOT IF I PUT IT HERE
```

I moved it just past the definition of the settings array (which I really haven't finished yet) and it broke. The weird thing is that when I commented out the $settings definition (with the code still after it) it still didn't work.

Comment: php-cli and php-cgi run with different levels of privilege by default (one is running through a web server and the other is run directly on your machine). My guess is that the security context of your web server does not have write access to the directory you're trying to write to.

Comment: Permissions error? Is the path the same in both? Does the bad script work when you run from shell with `php -f`?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll which is why i tried copying the code in question to a new php script.

Comment: @Anthony `php -f` didn't change the outcome. I copy/pasted the path and url to make sure i didn't make that mistake

Comment: In that case you have a race condition between `file_put_contents` and `exit`. Add the `exit` call to your fresh script and tell me if it still works consistently.

Comment: Fresh script still works with exit put in

Comment: hmm, okay. So much for Occam's Razor. Are you running *nix or Windows? What web server are you using? Is your "fresh" script in the same location as the one that's not working?

Comment: It says "Amazon Linux AMI". Both scripts are in the same directory.